# How can i append RN/ line to upper line without RN/ in C#?

Tags: c#

R/DOCS HK1/P/XX/123456789/XX/XXXXX/M/XXXXX/STAC

RN/K/OVER/FLOW

I need to merge above text like the below;

R/DOCS HK1/P/XX/123456789/XX/XXXXX/M/XXXXX/STACK/OVER/FLOW

The second line starts with RN/ which means everything after the slash should be appended to the previous line.

I searching with foreach. So i can't add as a string.

Comment: It is better to *explain* how the merge should be done rather than just show the final result and hope everyone understand exactly what you mean. Is it just as simple as "the second line starts with `RN/` which means everything after the slash should be appended to the previous line"?

Answer (score 0):

If the content you want to add from the second string always starts after "RN/", you can do it like this:

```
string string1 = "R/DOCS HK1/P/XX/123456789/XX/XXXXX/M/XXXXX/STAC";
string string2 = "RN/K/OVER/FLOW";

string result = string1 + string2.Substring(3);
```